# Java Volatile Variable

Tags: java, volatile

I am trying to understand volatile usage by the below example. I expect it to print 10 first and then 15 second. But most of the time i end getting 10 and 10.
Is some thing with the below code itself.

```
class T implements Runnable {

    private volatile int x = 10;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(x==10) {
            System.out.println(x);
            x = x+ 5;
        } else if(x==15) {
            System.out.println(x);
        }
    }
}


public class Prep {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        T t1 = new T();
        new Thread(t1).start();
        new Thread(t1).start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just have a race condition: both threads run in parallel, and thus you have (for example)

- thread 1 tests if x == 10 (true)
- thread 2 tests if x == 10 (true)
- thread 1 prints 10
- thread 2 prints 10
- ...

The fact that x is volatile here is irrelevant. The only thing that volatile guarantees in this example is that **if** thread 1 has already incremented x when thread 2 reads its value, then thread 2 will see the incremented value. But it doesn't mean that the two threads can't run in parallel as shown above.

Comment: @user3801948 Locking or immutability

Comment: @user3801948 - You have actually shared it.. You have not considered the fact that the statements inside the `if` block aren't guaranteed to execute together for a thread.

Comment: The problem is not sharing. The variable is shared. The problem is mutual exclusion. If you want a single thread to execute the run() method at a time, then it should be synchronized.

Answer (score 0):

This will work :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        T t1 = new T();
        new Thread(t1).start();
        try {
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000); // sleeping for sometime .
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        new Thread(t1).start();
    }

answer : 10 15
```

Reason : The operations

```
if(x==10) {
            System.out.println(x);
```

might have executed first for the first thread, then context would have switched back to Thread2 (race condition as JB Nizet explains..) so when both threads print the value of `x`, it is still 10.